# Simple JS function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone have an idea why my JS function is not working/my price div isn't showing anything at all?

HTML:

```
<div id="variant">
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="3"><span>A</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="12" checked="checked"><span>B</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="24"><span>C</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<div id="price"></div>
```

JS:

```
function setPrice() {
  if (document.getElementById('3').checked) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "19,99€";
  } else if (document.getElementById('12').checked) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "<<<";
  } else (document.getElementById('24').checked) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "xxx";
  }
}
```

Comment: How are  you calling setPrice? And a regular `else` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: At a minimum you'd need `setPrice();` but I'm guessing you want to call this function in the `onChange` or `onClick` event...

Comment: Starting an id with a number, or only using a number, is considered bad practice. http://stackoverflow.com/q/70579/1026459 has a list of appropriate values for the id.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for the quick answers! 1. Changed the id's (cause of number bad practice) and 2. added "else if". @War10ck yeah, that's exactly what I want to do! (onChange) - how can I insert the function in the easiest way? And is it a problem that the input is inside the label? (if I change it, the click functionality doesn't work anymore :( )

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=GOwhF2asm4 that's my current non-working prototype

Comment: Don't you look at the Javascript console for errors before you come here? It would have told you that you had a syntax error.

Comment: Please excuse me, I'm pretty new to JS and don't know how to check my code yet

Answer (score 2):

An "else" condition doesn't take in a statement, it would be IF / ELSE IF that takes in statements. Please see updated code snippet!

```js
function setPrice() {
  if (document.getElementById('3').checked) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "19,99€";
  } else if (document.getElementById('12').checked) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "<<<";
  } else if (document.getElementById('24').checked) {
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "xxx";
  }
}

setPrice();
```

```html
<div id="variant">
  <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="3" onClick="setPrice();"><span>A</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="12" onClick="setPrice();" checked="checked"><span>B</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" id="24" onClick="setPrice();"><span>C</span></label>
</div>
<br>
<div id="price"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from two sources.

1. You aren't calling `setPrice()`
2. Your line `else (document.getElementById('24').checked)`. There shouldn't be a condition if there isn't an `if`